# Using Intel's ifort on windows: How do I tell specify that the main file is not written in Fortran?

Tags: windows, compilation, fortran, intel-fortran

When compiling my C and fortran code on Linux, I use the flag `-nofor-main` to specify that the main routine is not written in fortran. (See [here for flag details](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/fortran-compiler-oneapi-dev-guide-and-reference/top/compiler-reference/compiler-options/compiler-option-details/linking-or-linker-options/nofor-main.html))

How do I specify that the main routine is not written in Fortran if I am compiling on windows?

Comment: @ArunJose_Intel, please don't add the tag [tag:intel-ifort] which has no other questions, while the tag [tag:intel-fortran] is already applied, has hundreds of questions and a tag wiki.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need on Windows for an option to specify that the main is not Fortran. You may, however, want to consider the `/libdir:noauto` option (in Visual Studio, Fortran > Libraries > Disable Default Library Search Rules > Yes.) This prevents the Fortran compiler from adding linker directives that pull in Fortran language support libraries. You would then have to specify these when you link the main program.

Otherwise, be very sure that you select the same set of support libraries (DLL vs. static, debug vs. release) as you do in your non-Fortran project.

Answer (score 0):

It appears I can just omit the specification and compilation remains successful.